# How to say that my English isn't very good?

Tags: adjectives, negation, conversation

> **A**: My English is poor.
>   **B**: My English is not good.
>   **C**: I am not good at English.
>   **D**: My English is bad.

Which one is more appropriate to use in conversation?

Comment: I prefer the one in your title. It uses the kind of vague understated language that English speakers use: *My English isn't very good*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looking at these different sentences formed correctly about an idea,  I don't think the OP's English is poor or bad. I would advise him not to be so humble. Nevertheless, he can use any of the sentences that he thinks is suitable.

Comment: Reminds me of a funny picture that I've seen before http://static.fjcdn.com/pictures/Very+true_d91f29_4835885.jpg