# What is the correct usage?

Tags: usage

> "I am good at English." Or "I am good in English."

Fluent sounds better. But again...

> "I am fluent at English." Or "I am fluent in English."

Comment: Related: http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/55763/9161 and http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/95700/9161

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When referring to a school subject we do say **at**

> I am good at Geography

so you could say

> I am good at English

If you are describing your capabilities in the language then **fluent** is probably better and then use **in**.

> I am fluent in English, Spanish and German

We may well phrase it differently, when emphasising some particular aspect of language skills

> I speak English fluently